# How to install a python library to a pulled docker image?

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I have pulled a docker image to run airflow (pucker/airflow) and it is running well. However, I can't manage to install a new python library on this image. I have read that you have to add the package in the docker file. However, I don't know where it is stored. I work on MacOSX.

Thanks for your help

Comment: please add your `Dockerfile` and add the `docker build..` command  (your usage).

Comment: You probably need a `Dockerfile`, which you base on the `airflow` image you're using, and in which you install your custom libraries

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you used `docker pull` and `docker run` commands?

If so, there is container running, you can check it by `docker ps`

And if you want to install python libraries in the container, you may go into the container via

```
docker exec -it container_id bash
```

and there you go with `pip install`

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, you only pulled a `puckel/docker-airflow` image from dockerhub, and you're simply running that image.

If you need to add extra libraries, and if you want to include the install of these libraries in a build process, you probably need a `Dockerfile`.
For instance, if you want to install `requests`, a minimalist Dockerfile could be as follows:

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow
RUN pip install requests
```

Create such a file in `myproject/`, then `cd` in `myproject/` and simply run `docker build .`
This will output a simple log such as:

```
Step 1/2 : FROM puckel/docker-airflow
 ---> 12753a529f9f
Step 2/2 : RUN python3 -m pip install requests
 ---> Running in 66860c8ca099
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (2019.3.9)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (1.25.3)
Removing intermediate container 66860c8ca099
 ---> 66b9d91c4c95
Successfully built 66b9d91c4c95
```

Then run `docker run 66b9d91c4c95` to instantiate the image you just created, or `docker run -it 66b9d91c4c95 bash` to open `bash` in it.

You can read on [docker tags](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) to replace `66b9d91c4c95` by a meaningful name.